# Children’s space book from around 1970

Tags: story-identification, books

I was in second grade in 1970 and my teacher read a book that I cannot find, but I don’t know the name.

All I have is that there were two main characters, maybe a young brother and sister, who travel to a faraway place, either a planet or a dream world, and they make friends with a little character named Jingles or Jangles. The little friend might be called Mr Jingles or Mr Jangles.

Wish I had more info to give.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly one of the [Wishing Chair](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/480019.Adventures_of_the_Wishing_Chair) books by Enid Blyton? They're about a young brother and sister, Peter and Mollie, who obtain a magic chair capable of taking them to far off magical places. They befriend a small pixie called Chinky after rescuing him from a giant's castle.